# Why does my clientWidth change when printed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to get the clientWidth of a 'th' element in angularJs with the following code:

```
var cols = this._element.find("th");

angular.forEach(cols, function(col) {
    var th = angular.element(col);
    console.log(th);
    console.log(th[0].clientWidth);
    th.css('width', th[0].clientWidth + "px");
});
```

When I print the element (first print) I get the following:

```
[th]
  0: th.ng-hide
    abbr: ""
    ...
    clientWidth: 0
```

Which is exactly the value that I would expect it to be (as it is a hidden element). However, when I try and access the clientWidth using:

```
th[0].clientWidth
```

I get a value of 12...

I have tried this with a number of elements (the full table and all of the th's, hidden and non-hidden) and all of them seem to have the appropriate values on the element, but give me incorrect values when I try and access them.

clientWidth and innerWidth are also consistently the same. Neither seem to reflect what I view on the element.

Any ideas as to why this may be?

Answer (score 0):

Using `Jquery`, if I print out the `clientWidth` for a `hidden` element, I get the clientWidth as `0`, whereas the `innerWidth` I get as the actual inner width of the element, is this what you were looking for ?

---

**Snippet :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.hide').css('display', 'none');
  var temp = "<br>innerWidth:" + $('.hide').innerWidth();
  temp += "<br>clientWidth(from [th] object):" + $('.hide')[0].clientWidth;
  var obj = new Object($('.hide'));
  $('#show').html(temp);
  console.log($('.hide').innerWidth());
  console.log($('.hide')[0].clientWidth);
  console.log($('.hide'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <th>Heading Shown</th>
  <th class='hide'>Heading Hidden</th>
</table>
<div id="show">
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @shmyq : Can you post your full code in the question ?

Comment: innerWidth() does not work on my elements because im pretty sure my angular app is using jqLite